# Is there a way to remove assemblies and namespaces declaration in asp.net mvc web.config file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, code-cleanup

i'm trying to make an empty asp.net mvc 3 application with razor engine(as much empty as possible) 
The one that VS2010 creates doesn't suit me, because there's too much mess in web.config files(+ plenty of scripts and styles and packages etc)
Is there an elegant way to hide this all mess somewhere else(but not in machine.config) and to deal with nice empty web.config file(at least at site root)?
And if not, maybe someone can give me some links about what all this autogenerated configurations mean(like dependentAssembly definition) and why they are needed.

Thank you, lets keep our code clean=)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Empty template when creating the ASP.NET MVC application and then have the following minimal web.config to successfully render a Razor view:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Also what you call *mess* in the web.config is simply a requirement if you want to use some functionalities such as forms authentication for example. But you could add the corresponding sections progressively according to your needs. I agree that there is plenty of useless crap in the default web.config generated by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with an empty ASP.net MVC 3 project. This one has the minimal amount of starting code/files for an MVC site. You can follow the below tutorial to get started on creating a MVC site from the empty ASP.net MVC 3 project:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1

Comment: thanks, but that's no quite what i asked, i've been there - right now i'm trying to get an "emptier" project